# CSS animate change from one class to another with ::after

Tags: css, html, animation

I am trying to use css animations to animate the change from one class to another. The basic idea is to animate a slider sliding from one edge to another when a user clicks on a button.

My code so far. https://jsfiddle.net/b5sqvrpz/

```
.verticalcontainer
{
 width: 100%;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
#pwrbtn.off:after
{
 display:block; 
 height: 100%;
 content: "■";
 color: blue;
 position: relative;
 left: -53%;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
 -o-transition: all 1s linear;
 transition: all 1s linear;
 }

#pwrbtn.on:after 
{
 display:block;
 height: 100%;
 content: "■";
 color: blue;
 position: relative;
 right: -53%;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
 -o-transition: all 1s linear;
 transition: all 1s linear;
 }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 classes for this because the "off" class can just be the default styling. Also, you're gonna want to use `left` positioning for both states, since you can't animate a change from `left` to `right`. Finally, you can simplify your CSS quite a bit, because you don't need to repeat CSS rules if they aren't changing. So for the "on" state you only need to define the new `left` position:

```js
$(function() {
 $('button').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('on');
  });
});
```

```css
.verticalcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#pwrbtn:after {
    display:block; 
    height: 100%;
    content: "■";
    color: blue;
    position: relative;
    left: -53%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
    #pwrbtn.on:after {
        left:53%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="verticalcontainer">
      <p>Off</p>
      <button id="pwrbtn"></button>
      <p>On</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the single pseudo element and transition `transform` for better performance.

```js
document.getElementById('pwrbtn').addEventListener('click',function() {
 this.classList.toggle('on');
})
```

```css
.verticalcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#pwrbtn:after {
  display: block;
  content: "■";
  color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
  -o-transition: all .25s linear;
  transition: all .25s linear;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#pwrbtn.on:after {
  color: blue;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="verticalcontainer">
  <p>Off</p>
  <button id="pwrbtn" class="on"></button>
  <p>On</p>
</div>
```